# Remove classes that are not in use from Android or/and Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project, shortcut

Does Eclipse have a function or/and a shortcut to identify or/and remove classes that are not in use by project, ideally something similar to the way that you can organize imports with `CTRL + SHIFT + O` (`command + SHIFT + O` for OSX users)?

Comment: @Lal "like CTRL + SHIFT + O (command + SHIFT + O for OSX users)" as an example!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/index.html) or [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html) or [Emma](http://www.eclemma.org/installation.html) or [CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/)

I don't think Eclipse Java would have something built-in for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

According to at least one reference, you can remove imports, as you noted:  [Vogella Eclipse Shortcuts](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html)

This should be removing unused imports, though.

Eclipse will usually highlight unused instances of objects as warnings to remove, but these is no shortcut for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Clean Up` function under `Source` menu.

For example, if you want to delete all classes which have `unused` warnings, you can do that like the following:

1. Open the Clean Up under the Source on menu bar.
2. Select `Use custom profile` radio button.
3. Select `Configure...` button on right side.
4. Select `Unnecessary Code` tab.
5. Tick `Remove unused private members`
6. OK and Finish

There is no shortcut for this function, but it might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Eclipse plugin UCDetector.

> UCDetector (Unnecessary Code Detector - pronounced "You See Detector")
>   is an eclipse PlugIn tool to find unnecessary (dead) public java code.
>   For example public classes, methods or fields which have no
>   references. UCDetector creates markers for the following problems,
>   which appear in the eclipse problem view:
>
> - Unnecessary (dead) code
> - Code where the visibility could be changed to protected, default or
>        private
> - Methods of fields, which can be final

This will not completely automate it, but at least you will find markers on the relevant code to delete.